# Add missing date rows in Power BI/Power Query and take value of row above

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Say I am importing something like the following into PowerBI:

```
          Date        |     Quantity       
|---------------------|------------------|
|       1/1/2018      |        22        |
|       1/3/2018      |        30        |
|       1/4/2018      |        10        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Where the external source table is a series of date, value rows with some date values missing. I'd like to execute some DAX/M to add any missing date rows into the data set, where 'Quantity' value is taken from the first date prior. So my resulting dataset would like like this:

```
          Date        |     Quantity       
|---------------------|------------------|
|       1/1/2018      |        22        |
|       1/2/2018      |        22        |
|       1/3/2018      |        30        |
|       1/4/2018      |        10        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Can this be done in PowerBI?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in DAX by creating a new table with all of the dates in your range as follows:

```
FullTable = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(MIN(Table1[Date]), MAX(Table1[Date])),
    "Quantity",
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        Table1[Quantity],
        Table1[Date],
        MAXX(
            FILTER(Table1, Table1[Date] <= EARLIER([Date])),
            [Date]
        )
    )
)
```

The `CALENDAR` function gives you a range of dates from you minimum to maximum dates in your original table. From there, we add a new column, `Quantity`, and define it as the value we get when looking up the `Quantity` in the original table for the date that was the maximum date occurring on or before the date in the current row.

Comment: Any hints on doing this when there is a combination of "date + place" to be filled with the previous quantity?

Comment: @DanielMöller If all the places have the same date range, then you should just need another condition pair in the LOOKUPVALUE. I.e. put `Table1[Place], [Place],` after `Table1[Quantity]` and before `Table1[Date]`.

Comment: The hard part is generating all the date and place pairs. Maybe `CROSSJOIN` the `CALENDAR` and `VALUES(Table1[Place])` and `FILTER` it to remove extraneous dates?

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query "M" code, see the comments to understand the different steps. Basically, it generates a new table with all the days, takes the Quantity values if avaliable and fill down the gaps.

Hope this help you.

```
let

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Test"]}[Content],
Converted = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),

// force conversion to date type to avoid problems if date values comes from an Excel table (in Excel they are numbers).

DatesCol = Converted[Date],

// list from Date column of Converted table

Ini = List.Min(DatesCol),
End = List.Max(DatesCol),
Size = Number.From(End - Ini) +1,
DatesNew = List.Dates(Ini, Size, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),

// generates a new list of dates from min to max

NewTable = Table.FromColumns({DatesNew},{"Dates"}),

// new table from new list of dates, column name is "Dates" not "Date".

Joined = Table.Join(NewTable,"Dates",Converted,"Date",JoinKind.FullOuter),

// join both table NewTable and Converted (from Source) and keep all the dates from the DatesNew list.

Removed = Table.RemoveColumns(Joined, "Date"),

// remove the original Date column as it's not needed.

Result = Table.FillDown(Removed,{"Quantity"})

// Fill Down the Quantity column.

in

Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Two items below should do it

```
// Query name fnGeT
(TableName as table, DateSearch as date) =>
let Source2 = Table.SelectRows(TableName, each [Date] < DateSearch and [quantity] <> null),
Max= Table.Group(Source2, {}, {{"Max", each List.Max([Date]), type date}}),
MaxDate = Table.SelectRows(Source2, each [Date] = Max{0}[Max]),
Value =  MaxDate{0}[quantity]
in Value
```

and

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Base = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"quantity", Int64.Type}}),

// Generate list of dates between Max and Min dates of Table1
DateRange = Table.Group(Base, {}, {{"MinDate", each List.Min([Date]), type date}, {"MaxDate", each List.Max([Date]), type date}}),
StartDate  = DateRange[MinDate]{0},
EndDate = DateRange[MaxDate]{0},
List ={Number.From(StartDate)..Number.From(EndDate)},
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(List, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
FullList = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type date}}),

//Right Anti Join to find dates not in original Table1   
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Base,{"Date"},FullList,{"Column1"},"Table2",JoinKind.RightAnti),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Table2"}),
Extras = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Table2", {"Column1"}, {"Date"}),

Combined = Base & Extras,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Combined, "Custom", each if [quantity]<>null then [quantity] else fnGet(Combined,[Date])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"quantity"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom", "quantity"}})
in #"Renamed Columns"
```